# SQL to combine ans on the same row of a quests

Tags: mysql

questions table

```
id     | question | id_answer  
-------------------------------
1      | name?    | 1          
2      | address? | 2
```

answers table

```
id     | answer   
------------------
1      | jonh     
2      | street   
3      | paul     
4      | gilbert  
5      | avenue   
6      | road
```

options table

```
id     | id_question | id_answer 
----------------------------------
1      | 1           | 1
2      | 1           | 3
3      | 1           | 4
4      | 2           | 2
5      | 2           | 5
6      | 2           | 6
```

I want to get something like this

```
id       | question | id_answer | id_1 | answer_1 | id_2   | answer_2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | name?    | 1         | 1    | jhon     | 4 or 5 | paul or gilbert
```

i need the answer correct and the one other random in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try this;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1f0d/4)

**MySQL 5.6**:

```
CREATE TABLE questions 
    (`id` int, `question` varchar(8), `id_answer` int)
;

INSERT INTO questions 
    (`id`, `question`, `id_answer`)
VALUES
    (1, 'name?', 1),
    (2, 'address?', 2)
;


CREATE TABLE answers 
    (`id` int, `answer` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO answers 
    (`id`, `answer`)
VALUES
    (1, 'jonh'),
    (2, 'street'),
    (3, 'paul'),
    (4, 'gilbert'),
    (5, 'avenue'),
    (6, 'road')
;


CREATE TABLE options 
    (`id` int, `id_question` int, `id_answer` int)
;

INSERT INTO options 
    (`id`, `id_question`, `id_answer`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 3),
    (3, 1, 4),
    (4, 2, 2),
    (5, 2, 5),
    (6, 2, 6)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select q.*, a.id as id_1, a.answer as answer_1, group_concat(a1.id ORDER BY a1.id separator ' or ') as id_2, group_concat(a1.answer ORDER BY a1.id separator ' or ') as answer_2
from questions q
left join answers a on a.id = q.id_answer
left join options o on q.id = o.id_question
left join answers a1 on a1.id = o.id_answer and a1.id <> q.id_answer
group by q.id, q.question
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1f0d/4/0)**:

```
| id | question | id_answer | id_1 | answer_1 |   id_2 |        answer_2 |
|----|----------|-----------|------|----------|--------|-----------------|
|  1 |    name? |         1 |    1 |     jonh | 3 or 4 | paul or gilbert |
|  2 | address? |         2 |    2 |   street | 5 or 6 |  avenue or road |
```

Comment: almost that... i only wanted the id_2 to be one of then and not both,
but from that i can try something... tks